# Css Боковая панель выезжающая справа. Как убрать полосу прокрутки снизу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Ни как мне допереть.. :(

**Резиновая вёрстка**. Боковая панель выезжающая при наведении (и при клике на другой объект) справа.
Кроме блока панели ни что за край не выходит.
Как убрать полосу прокрутки право/лево ту что снизу.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.bodis {
  position: static;
}

#podmeny {
  position: sticky;
  top: 19%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}

#bmeny {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.44s linear;
  padding: 0.4em;
  right: -14%;
  visibility: visible;
}

#podmeny:hover #bmeny {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}

aside {
  margin 1em 0.2em 0.6em 4em;
}

#bmeny p {
  border: ridge;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: purple;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 800;

}
```

```html
<div class="bodis">
  <div id="podmeny">
    <div id="bmeny">
      <aside>
        <a>
          <p>
            Нааа!
          </p>
        </a>
        <a>
          <p>
            Дааай!
          </p>
        </a>
        <a>
          <p>
            ББББББ
          </p>
        </a>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <p>Сонет 1</p>
    <p>Мой голос тих. Я отыскал слова<br>
      В пустых зрачках полночного покоя.<br>
      Божественно пуста моя глава,<br>
      И вне меня безмолвие пустое.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Скажи, я прав, ведь эта пустота<br>
      И есть начало верного служенья,<br>
      И будет свет, и будет наполненье,<br>
      И вспыхнет Роза на груди Креста?<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>...Но нет ответа. Тянется покой,<br>
      И кажется - следит за мной Другой,<br>
      Внимательно и строго ожиданье,<br>
      И я уже на грани естества,<br>
      И с губ моих срываются слова,<br>
      Равновеликие холодному молчанью...<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Сонет 2</p>
    <p>Равновеликие холодному молчанью<br>
      Струились реки посреди равнин.<br>
      Я плыл по рекам, но не дал названья<br>
      Ни берегу, ни камню средь стремнин.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Я проходил, я рекам был свидетель,<br>
      Я знал завет - не выносить суда,<br>
      И я не осквернил вопросом рта<br>
      И ничего сужденьем не отметил.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Лишь дельты вид мне отомкнул уста,<br>
      Я закричал, и гулко пустота,<br>
      Слова мои разбив об острова,<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Откликнулась бездонным тяжким эхом...<br>
      Я слышал крик и понимал со смехом:<br>
      Слова мертвы. Моя душа мертва.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Сонет 3</p>
    <p>Слова мертвы. Моя душа мертва.<br>
      Как сонный брег арктического моря.<br>
      И тело, смертно жаждущее рва,<br>
      Скрутило в узел судорогой горя.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Но там, на дне, у ключевых глубин,<br>
      Я ощущаю слабое биенье,<br>
      Сквозь сон мне тускло грезится рожденье<br>
      Иных, пока неведомых вершин.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Я жду сквозь боль, так исступлённо жду,<br>
      Когда рассвет предел положит льду,<br>
      Когда мой дух вернётся из скитанья...<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>До тканей сердца мглою поражён -<br>
      Я полон исполнением времён,<br>
      Я не ищу пред Небом оправданья.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Сонет 4</p>
    <p>Я не ищу пред Небом оправданья,<br>
      Я начинаю призрачный разбег,<br>
      В священной эпилепсии камланья<br>
      Нетопырём кружусь над гладью рек.<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Я проницаю горы и лощины,<br>
      Я различаю сущности стихий,<br>
      Схлестнувшиеся в танце теургий<br>
      И каждый миг являющие Сына...<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>Се время правды. Суть обнажена,<br>
      И льётся в полночь полная Луна,<br>
      И плоть моя не властна надо мной,<br>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p>И пламя звёзд, сквозь призму вечных вод<br>
      Пронзает ночь и дарит мне полёт<br>
      Над опьянённой ливнями Землёй...</p>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - вот так вот.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: **overflow-x** — Божечки ну как же я сам то не дошёл. Как просто и изящно! Спасибо вам. Grand mersi!

Answer (score 2):

Для позиционирования элемента `#bmeny` лучше всего воспользоваться свойством `transform`, а `overflow: hidden;` применить для элемента `.bodis`. Пример:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.bodis {
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

#podmeny {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}

#bmeny {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14%;
  transition: transform 0.44s linear;
  padding: 0.4em;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(80%);
  visibility: visible;
}

#podmeny:hover #bmeny {
  transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
}

aside {
  margin 1em 0.2em 0.6em 4em;
}

#bmeny p {
  border: ridge;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: purple;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodis">
  <div id="podmeny">
    <div id="bmeny">
      <aside>
        <a>
          <p>
            Нааа!
          </p>
        </a>
        <a>
          <p>
            Дааай!
          </p>
        </a>
        <a>
          <p>
            ББББББ
          </p>
        </a>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <p>Сонет 1</p>
    <p>Мой голос тих. Я отыскал слова<br> В пустых зрачках полночного покоя.<br> Божественно пуста моя глава,<br> И вне меня безмолвие пустое.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Скажи, я прав, ведь эта пустота<br> И есть начало верного служенья,<br> И будет свет, и будет наполненье,<br> И вспыхнет Роза на груди Креста?<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>...Но нет ответа. Тянется покой,<br> И кажется - следит за мной Другой,<br> Внимательно и строго ожиданье,<br> И я уже на грани естества,<br> И с губ моих срываются слова,<br> Равновеликие холодному молчанью...<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Сонет 2</p>
    <p>Равновеликие холодному молчанью<br> Струились реки посреди равнин.<br> Я плыл по рекам, но не дал названья<br> Ни берегу, ни камню средь стремнин.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Я проходил, я рекам был свидетель,<br> Я знал завет - не выносить суда,<br> И я не осквернил вопросом рта<br> И ничего сужденьем не отметил.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Лишь дельты вид мне отомкнул уста,<br> Я закричал, и гулко пустота,<br> Слова мои разбив об острова,<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Откликнулась бездонным тяжким эхом...<br> Я слышал крик и понимал со смехом:<br> Слова мертвы. Моя душа мертва.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Сонет 3</p>
    <p>Слова мертвы. Моя душа мертва.<br> Как сонный брег арктического моря.<br> И тело, смертно жаждущее рва,<br> Скрутило в узел судорогой горя.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Но там, на дне, у ключевых глубин,<br> Я ощущаю слабое биенье,<br> Сквозь сон мне тускло грезится рожденье<br> Иных, пока неведомых вершин.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Я жду сквозь боль, так исступлённо жду,<br> Когда рассвет предел положит льду,<br> Когда мой дух вернётся из скитанья...<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>До тканей сердца мглою поражён -<br> Я полон исполнением времён,<br> Я не ищу пред Небом оправданья.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Сонет 4</p>
    <p>Я не ищу пред Небом оправданья,<br> Я начинаю призрачный разбег,<br> В священной эпилепсии камланья<br> Нетопырём кружусь над гладью рек.<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Я проницаю горы и лощины,<br> Я различаю сущности стихий,<br> Схлестнувшиеся в танце теургий<br> И каждый миг являющие Сына...<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>Се время правды. Суть обнажена,<br> И льётся в полночь полная Луна,<br> И плоть моя не властна надо мной,<br> &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>И пламя звёзд, сквозь призму вечных вод<br> Пронзает ночь и дарит мне полёт<br> Над опьянённой ливнями Землёй...</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: Да! Но смешно: я сам пробовал overflow. Но видимо ставил в не тот слой. И у меня то блок не выезжал, то "резиновость" слетала. Спасибо!

Comment: И конечно мило что вы причесали весь код, но вы этим случайно убили эффект прилипания блока по вертикали. Так на заметку. ;-)